# When I try to debug my app on a device, my device does not show up in Google Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, ionic3, device

I run ionic cordova run android --device. The application starts on my device, but when I go to Google Chrome, my device is not showing. Remote Devices does no show anything. Is there a change in Chrome or a check that can be done?
Chrome Version 74.0.3729.157 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Ionic 3

I tried ionic cordova android with the name of my specific device but it also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following "adb devices" command in cmd or git bash of you project path everytime you connect your device where in it will show number of devices connected.And then you can run your project using "ionic cordova run android" and then you can debug in chrome by using "chrome://inspect/#devices"

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. My browser had hidden the devices manual on the bottom